# Rails ActiveRecord callback messup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

This is driving nuts. I have a dead simple callback functions to initialize and validate a class children as such:

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :bs
   after_initialize :add_t_instance
   validate :has_only_one_t

  protected

  def add_t_instance
      bs << B.new(:a => self, :type => "T") unless bs.map(&:type).count("T") > 0
  end

  def has_only_one_t
     unless bs.map(&:type).count("T") < 2
       errors.add(:bs, 'has too many Ts")
     end
  end

end
```

and now, here comes the magic at runtime:

```
a = A.new
>>[#<A>]
a.bs
>> [#<T>]
a.save
>> true
a.id
>> 15
```

so far it's all going great, but:

```
s = A.find(15)
s.bs
>>[#<T>,#<T>]
s.bs.count
>> 2
s.valid?
>> false
s.errors.full_messages
>> "Too many Ts"
```

What the heck am I missing here?!?! What in the world could be adding the second #T?

Comment: I have tried to recreate this, but get an error when trying to reload the 'A' object because subclass 'T' isn't defined.  Rails is trying to detect the subclass by convention because of the column name 'type'.  Do you have a class definition for 'T'?

Comment: yes I do. no problem there.

Answer (score 1):

Confusingly (to me at least) [`after_initialize`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#after_initialize-and-after_find) is called whenever an active record object is instantiated, not only after creating a new instance, but also after loading an existing one from the database. So you create the second B when you run `A.find(15)`.

You could solve the problem by checking whether you are dealing with a new record in your callback, e.g.

```
def add_t_instance
  if new_record?
    bs << B.new(:a => self, :type => "T") unless bs.map(&:type).count("T") > 0
  end
end
```

or you could place a condition on the `before_initialize` declaration itself, or perhaps try using a before_create callback.

Comment: Why isn't the `unless bs.map(&:type).count("T") > 0` preventing a second B from being instantiated?

Comment: Btw, doing test on new_record? fixes the problem. I just don't understand what is going on.

Comment: I don't understand why the unless doesn't work either. I tried to reproduce the problem but ran into issues with `type` being kind of a reserved word in ActiveRecord. I don't know whether you are using inheritance in your model, if not it might be best to rename that column if you can. I can't think of a reason why that would be causing the problem you are seeing but its possible.